# Iterating a Vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

So based on other examples I've found, I'm led to believe that this would be the proper code to iterate over m_vect:

```
for(vector<T>::iterator it = m_vect.begin(); it != m_vect.end(); ++it)
```

However, upon attempting to compile, I get the following error on that line:

```
heap.h:167:6: error: need ‘typename’ before ‘std::vector<T>::iterator’ because ‘std::vector<T>’ is a dependent scope
```

Like I said, I copied and adapted the line from another piece of code, so I'm really not sure what I'm doing right and wrong. Any insight?

To clarify, this is in a template function, and I have declared 'template '. m_vect is of type vector. Aaaand I don't know how to display less than and greater than properly...

Comment: What is T?  I think you need a real type there instead of just `T`.  Look the the type you defined for vector<>.

Comment: How is `m_vect` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be in a template function, and `vector<T>::iterator` is a type which is dependent on `T`, which is a template parameter.  Since templates can be specialized with unique definitions for any different type, the compiler has no way of being sure, until the template is actually instantiated, whether `vector<T>::iterator` is a type, or a static member.  If it is a static member, this does not make any sense, syntactically:

```
for(vector<T>::iterator it = m_vect.begin(); it != m_vect.end(); ++it)
```

What you need to do is tell the compliler that `vector<T>::iterator` is a type.  Use `typename` for that:

```
for(typename vector<T>::iterator it = m_vect.begin(); it != m_vect.end(); ++it)
```

If you read your error, you can see that this is exactly what your compiler is telling you.

Comment: I suppose it is. :| I guess I just thought it strange given that I've never needed to restate typename elsewhere before.

Comment: @TheBlab you should have to have it everywhere you have `class<T>::type` where `T` is a template.

Answer (score 6):

Thankfully in C++11 you can just have the compiler figure it out.  The compiler already knows what m_vect is, so you can tell it:

```
for (auto it= m_vect.begin(); ( it != m_vect.end()) ; ++ it ) { }
```

But wait, there's more.  In c++11 you can even just iterate over everything in `m_vect`

```
for (auto it : m_vect ) { }
```

Can you tell that I think iterating in C++03 was insane and I never saw anybody do it in real life, and in C++11 it is a thousand times better?

Comment: `But wait, there's more...` pay one, take two... +1

Comment: I really do like the simplicity implied here, but my compiler doesn't seem to agree. :/

Comment: @woolstar : I know I died a little time inside every time I forced myself to type out the C++98 / C++03 way when I was forcing myself to learn the STL...err...C++ standard library.  I often hid those iterator incantations behind typedefs to keep my fingers from falling off.  I've been programming C since 1992, and Pascal before that, and it just killed my sensibilities.  I can't wait until C++11 is supported in the enviroments where I still program in what's essentially "C with classes."  I hear we'll maybe get it in a few years...

Comment: @TheBlab You may have to add `--std=c++11` for GCC or Clang. If on MSVC, you need at least MSVC 12 for the range-based version (`auto it = m_vect.begin();` should work fine). If you're stuck with an older compiler, sorry :(

Comment: @TheBlab what poor compiler are you using?

Comment: Geany for Ubuntu. It's what I was set up with for a class.

Comment: Older versions of gcc were expecting the new standard to be done before 2010, so try `gcc -std=c++0x`

Comment: You don't need parentheses around condition.

Answer (score 0):

`T` needs to be an actual type. It should be the type of whatever is stored in the vector. Your `for` loop looks correct. You declared `m_vect` somewhere. The iterator needs the same time as whatever you declared `m_vect` (plus `::iterator` of course).

Comment: Shouldn't declaring 'template <typename T>' be sufficient?

Comment: No. When you declare the variable `it` you have to tell the compiler what type you expect it to have. (Though see @woolstar's answer above - apparently C++11 makes it easier.)

Comment: You can't make containers of `T`.  They have to be containers of **something real**.  Like `int` just for example.  So the iterator needs a type of things as well.

Comment: `T`, I'm pretty sure, is a template parameter to an enclosing class template or function template, and the OP is forwarding that parameter to `std::vector`, which is a perfectly correct and normal thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is something compilers are enforcing better now.

When you are using something derived from a template, you have to flag if it's being used as a type by adding `typename`. Then if the compiler knows that (for some insane reason) `vector<T>::iterator` is a method, it can immediately flag the error instead of heading into undefined behavior.

So just add `typename` like the message says:

```
for(typename vector<T>::iterator it = m_vect.begin(); it != m_vect.end(); ++it)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have  amodern enough compiler, you can replace `vector<T>::iterator` with `auto`.

Else, find the correct type to replace the `T` with for your vector.